# Angular pipe return class according to the days counted

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I created a Pipe to return the class based on the difference in days between the past and current value, but it always returns the class as if the date was always late.

I want to return based on the days closed to condition.

```
transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
    this.now = Date.now();
    this.now = new Date(this.now).toISOString();
    this.now = Date.parse(this.now);

    this.forecast = new Date(value).toISOString();
    this.forecast = Date.parse(this.forecast);

    this.diff = this.now - this.forecast;

    if(this.forecast < this.now){
      return 'is__border-left-danger';
    }

    else if (this.diff < 172800)  /** less than 2 days */
    {
      return 'is__border-left-danger';
    }

    else if (this.diff > 172800 || this.diff < 345600) /** between 2 days and 4 days */
    {
      return 'is__border-left-warning';
    } 

    else /** otherwise */
    {
      return 'is__border-left-success';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
this.now = Date.now();

```
// Make sure before subtracting dates both should be in milliseconds. If it's not in milliseconds then multiply it by 1000

this.forecast = new Date(value).toISOString();  // I didn't find it usefull
this.forecast = Date.parse(this.forecast);

this.diff = Math.abs(this.now - this.forecast); // Your comparison below need only diff so use Math.abs() function

if(this.forecast < this.now){
  return 'is__border-left-danger';
}

else if (this.diff < 172800)  /** less than 2 days */
{
  return 'is__border-left-danger';
}

else if (this.diff > 172800 || this.diff < 345600) /** between 2 days and 4 days */
{
  return 'is__border-left-warning';
} 

else /** otherwise */
{
  return 'is__border-left-success';
}
```

}

Check this one it may useful => https://www.epochconverter.com/